# Difference between 22 and 22/tcp rule in firewall

Tags: ssh, firewalls

I have those two rules in UFW, but no idea what is the difference between [1] and [2]?

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

Should I improve those rules? If so, how?

Comment: I googled "UFW port" and this was the top hit: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04 It explains it

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation? Are you aware of UDP and TCP? In what way do you want to improve the rules?

Comment: I know the link. I have seen documentation but I have no experience. I asked because I suppose that someone who has more experience will answer. My goal is to have maximum security.

Comment: So, then if you know the documentation, then you know the difference between the 2 lines ... And you would also know which one is more relevant in your environment ... The link explains the difference.

Comment: Are you aware of what UDP and TCP are?

Comment: Yes, I am aware, for me [1] is not needed and is redundant, but I am not sure.

Comment: So, hold on, you already *knew* that [1] means that it blocks both UDP/TCP (because you've read the documentation and read the link), and that [2] blocks only TCP, right? And you are asking *us* which one is redundant? Well, do you have a service running on UDP port 22? This is a strange way to ask this question if you already have this knowledge. If you ***really*** just wanted to know which one is redundant, then you should rewrite the question and provide context for what services are running and more details on the network ...

Comment: If, however, you just didn't look this up before posting the question, then you have the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP said they already knew the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are separate rules, they are checked each time a new connection arrives. In your case you have two rules:

1. allowing all incoming connections on port 22 with both TCP and UDP protocols
2. same but it only applies to connections on the TCP protocol, which is not needed in your case, because you have a rule with high priority (1 > 2) that allows traffic on both protocols.

If you want to secure your SSH server, you can do it by allowing only specific IP addresses to access port 22, use port knocking or similar methods.